# Dynamic ContextMenu

Tags: c#, xml, xaml

I have a problem. After Click MenuItem header: "System.XML.XMLElement".

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

IpLisr.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<IPList>
  <header Name="1" Click="1" Tag="1">192.168.0.100</header>
  <header Name="2" Click="2">192.168.0.101</header>
  <header Name="3" Click="3">192.168.0.102</header>  
</IPList>
```

list.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="XMLMenu" Source="IPList.xml" XPath="IPList/header"/>    
</ResourceDictionary>
```

XAML:

```
<MenuItem Header="IP" DataContext="{StaticResource XMLMenu}" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Click="MenuItem_Click_IP"/>
```

*.cs

```
private void MenuItem_Click_IP(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  MenuItem obMenuItem = e.OriginalSource as MenuItem;
  MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0} just said Hi!", obMenuItem.Header)); 
  // Need a header of IPList.xml. How get that? 
}
```

Comment: what error message do you get?

Comment: Looks like menu item header caption is assinged XMLElement value instead of string value. It is then converted to string using default ToString() method which by default returns type name "System.XML.XMLElement".